# Can't getting expected values from REST API via GET method using javax-rs libraries

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

For example I defined two classes Like class Student method  and Class Main. I registered student resource  class with jersey. 
In  Student class have  setters  and Main class have setting the student details.
In order to get the student details using REST what i set for this class,I am getting default values of Student class.

I wrote the code example below.

```
 @Path("/student")
    public class Student{
    int id;
    String name;
    //setters
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getALL(){
    return id;
    }
}
```

When i hit the above program from browser getting default values of studentclass

```
Public class MainClass{
//set the values for student class
}
```

Result from my  browser: 0

Answer (score 0):

Set value in main method is no use. Each request creates new Student instance. You can debug about this, you will find the student objects point to different memory addresses. Right way is to set

```
@Path("/student")
    public class Student{
    int id = 1;
    String name = "Sriram";
    //setters
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getALL(){
    return id;
    }
}
```

It's just for your simple REST API test. Actual service will get real data and return.

Comment: Thank you @bejond.